# HighChart HighStock Error: Invalid negative value for <rect>

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I'm getting the following errors when I load my view and HighChart chart.

[image]

I narrowed it down to the use of the Navigator (timeline focus bar), I'm using it in my chart:

[image]

Here is what it looks like, inside of my **chartConfig.options** if I disable the navigator I won't get those errors, however this is a feature I want to use.

```
navigator : {
    enabled: true,
    adaptToUpdatedData: true,
    // enabled: false,
    // adaptToUpdatedData: false,
    series : {
        data : vm.navigatorData
    }
},
```

Now for the default data, this is how I create my Array, I don't have data to fill in the chart yet, until the user takes an action:

```
vm.navigatorData = [];
var count = 0;
// creates a chart with 97 x points all with 0 y value:
_.times(97, function() {
    dayHolder.push({
        'x': count++,
        'y': 0
    });
});
```

Comment: Looks like [this issue](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5041#issuecomment-184597986). Could you try out the solution posted by Jon?

Comment: Thanks, I updated my highstocks from 4.2 to 4.2.3, that fix by Jon wasn't included in 4.2.3 for some reason. However the correct fix is below by Jordan, will implement here in a few.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because vm.navigatorData is empty.  You should fill this with data before initializing the chart.